# Update nested array of Objects in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to update the 'categories' array located in the 'menu'(model) schema.
I would like to change the name of a specific Category.

The 'category' schema is just a schema - not a model...
this code is in a nosejs server

Here are my Schemas  :

```
   const menuSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    restName: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    categories: [categorySchema],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)
```

The 'category' Schema:

```
  const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {

    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)
```

I try to do this :

```
try {
let updateMenu = await Menu.updateOne(
  { _id: menuId, "categories.$.name": oldCatName },
  { $set: { "categories.$.name": newName } }
)
```

Just can't understand this in mongoose

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your menuSchema "categories" shoud be an array of objectId refer to other schema like

```
categories = [productId: {
              type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: 'categorySchema',}
             ]
```

and afterthat populate categories where you want to get categories name. See this [mongoose documentation link on populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/populate.html)